# How does one extract classical results from QED Lagrangian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law

A well known result from classical electrodynamics for the total energy density of a charged spherical shell is,

$$
u = \frac{3e^2}{32 \pi^2 \varepsilon_0 r^4},
$$
How would you extract that result from the QED Lagrangian?
$$
\mathfrak{L} = - \frac{1}{4\mu_0}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} + i\hbar c \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi - mc^2 \bar{\psi} \psi + {ec} \bar{\psi} A_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}\psi.
$$

Comment: From this Lagrangian calculate the Stress-Energy tensor for gauge field. and  energy density is just 00 component.

Comment: I don't think that is right.  Since this is a static situation, I would expect that the kinetic energy terms would be zero.

Comment: we should take Stress energy tensor of  only the interaction term which is important here. and also vector potential should have only scalar part.and also take the non relativistic limit of spinor.

Comment: So we are only interested in $ec\bar{\psi}A_0 \gamma^0 \psi$?

Comment: If that is the case then there is a problem because that would end up giving the classical electron radius and we know from experiment the classical electron radius is not true.

Comment: If you integrate out the Dirac field, you end up with the  [Euler-Heisenberg Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Heisenberg_Lagrangian), this will lead to the result plus correction terms due to vacuum polarization.

Comment: Thanks but not sure how one would get a charged spherical shell from that.  It looks like it is mainly for photon-photon scattering.